# two days before Previousday dax

Tags: excel, dax

I have added a measure to calculate difference to yesterday's figures however
when it is Monday's figure it returns blank instead of comparing against Friday's figure.

Is there a way of asking sales figure from two days ago, I tried deducting 2 as per

```
previous Day Sales:=CALCULATE(
sum(Sales[1]),
PREVIOUSDAY(Calender[Date]-2))
```

But it didn't work

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
B

Comment: Am thinking of a formula. Please share a screenshot or an excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming in your context is present `Sales[Date]` or `Calendar[Date]` column you can get the previous date with sales by using a `FILTER`:

```
Previous Day Sales :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Sales ),
        Sales[Date]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( Sales[Date] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( Sales ),
                    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Sales, EARLIER ( Sales[Date] ) < Sales[Date] ) )
                )
            )
    )
)
```

This is an example in Power BI, but works in Power Pivot (Excel) too.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: it worked fine if I use  the date column on the table Sales but if I use dates from Calendar table it get messed up ?! ..  :(

Comment: @Matrix1977, Are Calendar[Date] and Sales[Date] related in your model? That wouldn't happen if your tables are properly related.

Comment: both tables are linked formula , maybe I am referring to the wrong table on the folrmula ?.. Previous Day Sales:=CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
    FILTER (
        All(Calender),
        Calender[Date]
            = CALCULATE (
                MAX ( Calender[Date] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( Sales ),
                    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Calender, EARLIER (Calender[Date]) < Calender[Date] ) )
                )
            )
    )
)

Comment: @Matrix1977, I am seeing you are using Calender table across the whole expression: `FILTER(ALL(Calender)..` Use the `Sales` table instead, check my expression I am using Sales[Date] column where you are using Calender[Date]. If your Sales table doesn't include a Date column explain how these are related.

Comment: Sales is linked to Calendar through columns Sales[date] and Calendar[date]. Calendar[date] is the table with unique values.

Comment: @Matrix1977, In that case you can use `Sales` table and `Sales[Date]` column as my original expression. It doesn't matter if you use Calendar[Date] in the pivot table, the expression must use `Sales` table.